# Display Google location in Android layout

Tags: android, gmsplacepicker

I am using Google Place Picker to get the user current location and send it to the other user in a chat dialog, but what I want is to display that location in the chat dialog as a message element.

[image: target image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestions would be to get the picked location's **latitude** and **longitude**, then send it to user/server as per your system congfiguration. Then in other user side, show the google map view in inside chatbox, you can use [MapFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment) for this, then add location marker at the received latitude and longitude in google map.